# orchard cms twitter stopped working

Tags: twitter, orchardcms

My Twitter widget suddenly stopped working. My site is hosted with Arvixe, Azure, a local ISP  and on a local server (different DNS entries). Without making changes my twitter widget stopped listing tweets. I tried different Twitter accounts, no change. External inputs (Facebook like and online contact forms are working 100%).

Anyone experiencing the same issue?

My conclusion so far:
1. Was working, no need to reinstall the widget
2. Multiple sites were working without making changes
3. Changing twitter account information, same result

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The twitter API v1.0 has been deprecated so any widget using this will need to be upgraded to v1.1 https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview

You have not specified the module you are using, but the one I use https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.LatestTwitter has a new version released which is working perfectly with the new API. If you are using a different module see if they have a new version or contact the developer about an update.

Answer (score 0):

I had Orchard.Module.LatestTwitter 1.2.1 installed and reinstalled the module. Once reinstalled two new fields appeared (OAuth Consumer Key and OAuth Consumer Secret).

I created a Twitter application (https://dev.twitter.com/apps) which generated OAuth Consumer Key and OAuth Consumer Secret values.

**Note:** I am using a *dev environment (e.g.localhost)* and specified valid www url’s within Twitter - it worked after stopping and starting the website within WebMatrix.

Thanks for the guidance.